# Facebook Marketing API permanent Access Token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm building an app which acts as a simplified layer of the Facebook Ads manager. It can create ads trough the Facebook marketing api.

There are also other services such as adespresso or manychat which offer such a service.

Now I'm wondering about the following: when a user in my app authenticates, I get a short-lives user-access-token. As far as I understand the documentation, there is no way of refreshing this token. The user would need to login again.

When I look at the above mentioned apps however, I stay authenticated. I don't have to re-authenticate each time I'm using the app. So does anyone have a suggestion of how to do it like them?

Comment: Tokens can be extended to be valid for up to 60 days, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing

Comment: Within the realm of the Marketing API, there are also system users, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/system-users